# MySQL regexp parentheses and param 1,2,3,

Tags: mysql, regex

How to in MySQL regexp use founded values in parentheses?
For example, REGEXP '(.)\1' - "\1" is mean same symbol as founded in () and will be founded aa, bbb, cccc strings. But its not work in MySQL.

Comment: did u want to find the result value separated by comma

Comment: I want find double+ symbols in string: For example "**aa** **bbb** some words **cc** some another".

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's regexps are not as powerful as others.  Most backslash things are not implemented.  Experiment...

```
+----------------------+
| 'aaa' REGEXP '(.)\1' |
+----------------------+
|                    0 | -- fails to get what you want
+----------------------+
+---------------------+
| 'a1' REGEXP '(.)\1' |
+---------------------+
|                   1 | -- it tested this, instead
+---------------------+
```

Not quite what you want, but they return TRUE:

```
+----------------------+
| 'aaa' REGEXP 'a{2,}' |
+----------------------+
|                    1 |
+----------------------+
+--------------------+
| 'aaa' REGEXP 'aa+' |
+--------------------+
|                  1 |
+--------------------+
+--------------------+
| 'abc' REGEXP '..+' |
+--------------------+
|                  1 |
+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not the same as find any double char. If mysql does not support full regex syntax, that is all what i can do.